# Drag and drop With Socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a multiplayer card game with node, express and socket io. I'm having issues being able to pass drag and drop actions made by one player to the screen of a second player connected.

Basically I use this function to handle the drop event on client side. I get the id of the card moved and then append it to the dropzone where its moved

```
function handleBoxDrop(e) {
    const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    let dropzone = e.target;
    socket.emit('drop', id);

    socket.on('drop', (id) => {
      let temp = document.getElementById(id);
      dropzone.appendChild(temp);
    });

    e.dataTransfer.clearData();
  }
```

and on server side I used this:

```
o.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('drop', (id) => {
    io.emit('drop', id);
  });
});
```

But when I move a card, The card doesn't move on the other browser or moves to the wrong place. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move the socket.on function to outside of the handle drop function

```
function handleBoxDrop(e) {
   '''your code'''
}

socket.on('drop', e => {
   '''append to dropzone'''
})
```

The socket.on method creates a listener and only needs to be created once. You can call it right after you instantiate the socket object.

```
const socket = websocket()
socket.on('drop', e => {})
```

Comment: If I move the socket.on outside the handle drop function, then I wont have access to the e.target(dropzone) to appendChild

Comment: The event target should be the object you’re wanting to move. If you have a single drop zone you should store it as a variable outside the scope of the drop function. If you have multiple drop zones you should pass which drop one you’re wanting to use through the web socket as well. Every time you call this function you are creating a new even listener for the ‘drop’ event. This will cause problems and you only need one

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks. I passed the dropzone id in the socket.emit() just as I did for the card id and that did the trick. Dont know why I never thought of that. Thanks Man